# How to show addin in Outlook web app when composing mail?

Tags: outlook, office-js, office-addins, outlook-web-addins, outlook-web-app

I used office-generator to scaffold out an Outlook addin and it seems to show up and run when mail opened in read mode but its not showing up in the addins section when a new mail is being composed. I wanted to show the addin to show up in compose mode and once clicked open the addin in pane.

Following is the generated manifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<OfficeApp xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/appforoffice/1.1"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns:bt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/officeappbasictypes/1.0"
  xmlns:mailappor="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides/1.0" xsi:type="MailApp">
  <Id>5258dea2-7a90-4263-a6e9-a6a9b69c032a</Id>
  <Version>1.0.0.0</Version>
  <ProviderName>Contoso</ProviderName>
  <DefaultLocale>en-US</DefaultLocale>
  <DisplayName DefaultValue="FirstOutlookAddin"/>
  <Description DefaultValue="A template to get started."/>
  <IconUrl DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/assets/icon-32.png"/>
  <HighResolutionIconUrl DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/assets/icon-80.png"/>
  <SupportUrl DefaultValue="https://www.contoso.com/help"/>
  <AppDomains>
    <AppDomain>contoso.com</AppDomain>
  </AppDomains>
  <Hosts>
    <Host Name="Mailbox"/>
  </Hosts>
  <Requirements>
    <Sets>
      <Set Name="Mailbox" MinVersion="1.1"/>
    </Sets>
  </Requirements>
  <FormSettings>
    <Form xsi:type="ItemRead">
      <DesktopSettings>
        <SourceLocation DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/taskpane.html"/>
        <RequestedHeight>250</RequestedHeight>
      </DesktopSettings>
    </Form>
  </FormSettings>
  <Permissions>ReadWriteItem</Permissions>
  <Rule xsi:type="RuleCollection" Mode="Or">
    <Rule xsi:type="ItemIs" ItemType="Message" FormType="Read"/>
  </Rule>
  <DisableEntityHighlighting>false</DisableEntityHighlighting>
  <VersionOverrides xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides" xsi:type="VersionOverridesV1_0">
    <Requirements>
      <bt:Sets DefaultMinVersion="1.3">
        <bt:Set Name="Mailbox"/>
      </bt:Sets>
    </Requirements>
    <Hosts>
      <Host xsi:type="MailHost">
        <DesktopFormFactor>
          <FunctionFile resid="Commands.Url"/>

          <!-- Message Compose -->
          <ExtensionPoint xsi:type="MessageComposeCommandSurface">
            <OfficeTab id="TabDefault">
              <Group id="msgComposeCmdGroup">
                <Label resid="GroupLabel"/>
                <Control xsi:type="Button" id="msgComposeInsertGist">
                  <Label resid="TaskpaneButton.Label"/>
                  <Supertip>
                    <Title resid="TaskpaneButton.Title"/>
                    <Description resid="TaskpaneButton.Tooltip"/>
                  </Supertip>
                  <Icon>
                    <bt:Image size="16" resid="Icon.16x16"/>
                    <bt:Image size="32" resid="Icon.32x32"/>
                    <bt:Image size="80" resid="Icon.80x80"/>
                  </Icon>
                  <Action xsi:type="ShowTaskpane">
                    <SourceLocation resid="Taskpane.Url"/>
                  </Action>
                </Control>
                <Control xsi:type="Button" id="msgComposeInsertDefaultGist">
                  <Label resid="FunctionButton.Label"/>
                  <Supertip>
                    <Title resid="FunctionButton.Title"/>
                    <Description resid="FunctionButton.Tooltip"/>
                  </Supertip>
                  <Icon>
                    <bt:Image size="16" resid="Icon.16x16"/>
                    <bt:Image size="32" resid="Icon.32x32"/>
                    <bt:Image size="80" resid="Icon.80x80"/>
                  </Icon>
                  <Action xsi:type="ExecuteFunction">
                    <FunctionName>insertDefaultGist</FunctionName>
                  </Action>
                </Control>
              </Group>
            </OfficeTab>
          </ExtensionPoint>


        </DesktopFormFactor>
      </Host>
    </Hosts>


    <Resources>
      <bt:Images>
        <bt:Image id="Icon.16x16" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/assets/icon-16.png"/>
        <bt:Image id="Icon.32x32" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/assets/icon-32.png"/>
        <bt:Image id="Icon.80x80" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/assets/icon-80.png"/>
      </bt:Images>
      <bt:Urls>
        <bt:Url id="Commands.Url" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/commands.html"/>
        <bt:Url id="Taskpane.Url" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/taskpane.html"/>
      </bt:Urls>
      <bt:ShortStrings>
        <bt:String id="GroupLabel" DefaultValue="Git the gist"/>
        <bt:String id="TaskpaneButton.Label" DefaultValue="Insert gist"/>
        <bt:String id="TaskpaneButton.Title" DefaultValue="Insert gist"/>
        <bt:String id="FunctionButton.Label" DefaultValue="Insert default gist"/>
        <bt:String id="FunctionButton.Title" DefaultValue="Insert default gist"/>
      </bt:ShortStrings>
      <bt:LongStrings>
        <bt:String id="TaskpaneButton.Tooltip" DefaultValue="Displays a list of your gists and allows you to insert their contents into the current message."/>
        <bt:String id="FunctionButton.Tooltip" DefaultValue="Inserts the content of the gist you mark as default into the current message."/>
      </bt:LongStrings>
    </Resources>

  </VersionOverrides>
</OfficeApp>
```

Comment: What version (and build #) of Outlook are you trying this on? I am unable to repro on the client I have, your add-in shows up in compose for me just fine. I've tried online OWA and recent subscription version of Windows Desktop Outlook (for Microsoft 365).

Comment: Version 15.1 ‎(Build 225.42)‎

Comment: My version of OWA is: Version 15.1 ‎(Build 225.42)‎,  Is it the version problem?

Comment: Well this appears to correlate to the very first release of Exchange Server 2016... 17 (!) cumulative updates have been released for that server version since its original release late 2015, could you please update your Exchange Server to most recent released cumulative update at the time of this writing, and try again?

CU17: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4556414/cumulative-update-17-for-exchange-server-2016